# how exactly with keyword in python works

Tags: python, python-3.x

i came across with keyword in scrapy and interested to learn about with keyword in short and simple

Comment: `print(*map(''.join, names), sep='\n')`

Comment: @manee  We collect solution to unique problems, problems that already got a solution get closed as duplicate. Thats nothing bad, just directs you to the "older" post that solves your problem. Read the duplicates answers - they solve yours.

Comment: @PatrickArtner please remove ban on this question i have changed it

Comment: @maneesh There is no "ban" on this question. It is a duplicate of other questions that answer yours. Beside that you got a perferctly fine answer below (that you already accepted). Having questions closed as Duplicate is nothing inherintly bad, it just curates the site and leads people that find your question to others that were there before yours and also answer it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Beside that - you **_never ever_** change one question into something different that invalidates its already given answers. You'll invalidate all the work people took on them to help you out. Ask a new question if you have a specific question that is on-topic - see [ask] for details. That "edit" of yours does not qualify as a valid question here.

Comment: @PatrickArtner i know but due to too many demerits stackoverflow is not allowing me to post any new question. what can i do

Comment: Circumventing our rules it not helpful. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
names = [['N', 'I', 'T', 'I', 'N'], ['I', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'I']]

for s in map(''.join, names):
    print(s)
```

Comment: Sorry got confuesed. As the inner strings all contain strings it works - if you have mixed innner lists (say `[[ 1,"hi"],["hi",2]]` - it won't because `''.join(iterable)` wants strings only).

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes, in that case you can call `str()` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
names = [['N', 'I', 'T', 'I', 'N'], ['I', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'I']]
formatted = [''.join(name) for name in names]
print(*formatted, sep='\n')
```